# How can I disable popup-SMS notifications (2.2 Froyo, HTC Evo)?

Tags: sms, notifications

I have the HTC evo, and I need to disable the popup SMS notifications. I have the stock notification app and chompsms. I disabled all notifications from stock, and chomp has no option for popups (even when disabled this happens). Basically every SMS = a popup stating that heres your message, what to do: Done, Reply, etc. I would really rather it be a notification on the bar and not a popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. This was a "quick reply" feature of chompsms. Wow. That was hard to find. Guess will accept this in 2 days.